# Restore data from sql server 2008 transaction log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transaction-log

I have a sql server 2008 database that is in Full Recovery mode.

I haven't made a backup of the database or log.

Some data was inadvertently deleted from the database. I would like to go back to before the point in time that the data was deleted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Because you never did a backup, the database was not in full recovery mode, was in simple recovery mode (despite the setting), see [is that database REALLY in the FULL recovery mode?](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/New-script-is-that-database-REALLY-in-the-FULL-recovery-mode.aspx). So the log was recycled since the delete occurred, making it impossible to recover anything.

But it begs the question: if you did set the recovery model to FULL, why didn't you also took a backup immediately?

Comment: That begs my answer: I didn't know that there was a such thing as "pseudo-SIMPLE" recovery mode.

Comment: The fn_dblog() function is more helpful to find out the accidentally deleted transactions when you don't have the backup of your transaction logs.